# How to change the color from Picker in Xamarin Mac?

Tags: colors, xamarin.forms, picker, xamarin.mac

I have a picker on my Xamarin mac app, I want to change the background color and the border color (blue), How can I do that?

[image]

```
Picker picker1 = new Picker { Items = { translateExt.transltR("Option1"), "Option2", "Option3" }, SelectedIndex = outputMode, WidthRequest = 210, TextColor = Color.FromHex(fileManagerPlatform.getColorText()), VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand};
picker1.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
```

The previous code works on Android, iOs, UWP to change the background color, but not on Mac.

Comment: Are you referring to change the style of the Picker control in Xamarin iOS?

Comment: No, In Xamarin Mac I want to change the style but i thing is not so easy.